# REST API in Parse to interact with an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rest, parse-platform

I get familiar with [Parse Mobile App Platform](https://www.parse.com/) recently. It can be use to add a backend to the mobile applications. It includes a `REST API` that lets you interact with Parse from anything that can send an `HTTP` request like my **iOS app**.

I am looking for some easy to learn tutorials. Do you know some one?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're looking for a tutorial on - using Parse?  Making http requests from iOS?  Synchronizing data?

Comment: I look for something that show how to interact with [REST API in Parse](https://parse.com/docs/rest) from an iPhone app. Is it clear?

Comment: What did you end up going with?

Comment: I think you are right about using iOS API. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has an iOS API so although you could, you don't have to go down to the http level and do your own serialization and deserialization of objects.

This guide shows interactions:
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide

Since you're making http calls, I would highly recommend looking at their async APIs using blocks so you don't block the UI thread.  For example:

```
[gameScore saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
     // The gameScore saved successfully.
  } else {
    // There was an error saving the gameScore.
  }
}];
```

So, prefer all methods ending "WithBlock".  Also see: [How do i run a proccess without blocking user interface in my iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508246/how-do-i-run-a-proccess-without-blocking-user-interface-in-my-iphone-app/7508285#7508285)

Comment: Parse iOS API is total bloat fest. REST Api avoids that.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and try the tutorials right at their webpage: [Parse tutorials](https://www.parse.com/tutorials).