# performSelectorOnMainThread with multiple parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to perform this action on the main thread:

```
[curItem.mButton setBackgroundImage:newArt forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So I do this...

```
cWrapperObject* obj = [cWrapperObject alloc];
[obj setupParams :curItem.mButton :newArt];
[obj performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageForButton) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I feel like this is bad, does anyone has any suggestions on how I could approach this differently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another option is GCD.  You can invoke a block on the main queue which gets run serially when the run loop runs.  blocks aren't limited to one object like performSelectorOnMainThread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // code here
});
```

I wrote a more comprehensive comparison of performSelectorXXX and GCD here complete with samples:

[GCD, Threads, Program Flow and UI Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290931/gcd-threads-program-flow-and-ui-updating/7291056#7291056)

Also, here's another related SO post:

[GCD to perform task in main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662360/gcd-to-perform-task-in-main-thread)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to pass only one parameter, you should set up "withObject:" argument in method `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone`. So your method should be declared as

```
-(void)setImageForButton:(id)parameter
```

and you should invoke method on main thread with:

```
[obj performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageForButton:) withObject:newArt waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Note ':' in `@selector(setImageForButton:)` this means that this method will be messaged with one argument, passed in `withObject:`