# Copy Files without freezing GUI

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

OK, so basically here's what I want to do :

- I have a list of files in my **app bundle**, e.g. in folder `myData` (please note: there are lots of files/folders within subfolders/etc)
- I want to **copy the whole file tree** to a given location on user's disk
- I need to have **access to each separate file** being copied, since some of them will need to be processed before being copied.

How would you go about that? Any ideas?

---

**P.S.**

- I know about `NSFileWrapper`'s `writeFile:atomically:updateFilenames`, but it doesn't gie me access to each file
- I already have a method for getting the file tree for a specific folder. However, it still seems to me kinda slow. Is there any built-in (or more Cocoa-friendly) way for that?
- Since there are quite a lot of files, the whole process must run so that the GUI does *not* freeze

Comment: in depth explanation here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290931/gcd-threads-program-flow-and-ui-updating/7291056#7291056

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use Grand Central Dispatch(GCD) to run method in asynchronously thread using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // user disk space - will use user document
    NSString *docuemntPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    // app bundle folder
    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *folderPath = [bundleRoot stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"aFolder"];

    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:folderPath].allObjects;

    for (NSString *aFile in [files objectEnumerator]) { 
        NSString *copyPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFile];
        NSString *destPath = [docuemntPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFile];

        NSError *error;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:copyPath toPath:destPath error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Copying successful");
            // here add a percent to progress view 
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Copying error: %@", error.userInfo);
        } 
    }

  // When the copying is finished update your UI 
  // on the main thread and do what ever you need with the object 
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self someMethod:myData];
  });
});
```

and on your main thread use a UIProgressView to indicate the progress of file operation from the number of files/folder.