# WkWebView copy string app freeze

Tags: swift, wkwebview, uipasteboard

I have a weird issue, when a user is selecting text in a WkWebView and clicks copy my app freezes up. There is no code run for copying it's just a user using the wkWebView normally.

No crash or error is shown but the log shows:

`Returning local object of class NSString
PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected.`

When i pause the debugger this is all I see:

[image: threads]

How do i go about debugging this? Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why that would take long, but try to do the copy action in a separate thread, e.g. not the GUI thread. You may use [Grand Central Dispatch(GCD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333143/copy-files-without-freezing-gui) to run methods in another thread.

Comment: can you please show us some code?

Comment: It's wkWebView that loads a pdf. The actual copying is not a code that is being executed just the user zooming and marking text in the pdf.

Comment: What are you copying?

Comment: When a user tries to copy text from a pdf this occurs

Comment: can you reproduce the same error with the same PDF in Safari? Can you maybe provide us with a minimum sample project where the error is reproducible? Have you tried setting the symbolic breakpoints for error in Xcode?

Comment: Is it maybe feasible for you to use a PDFView instead, if you are just using the wkwebview for displaying a PDF?

Comment: @andromedainiative try to use contentEditable. NSString htmlString="......<div contentEditable=\"true\">.."

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi sorry for my late reply, I sadly can't use anything else since the content that will be displayed can be either plain html or a pdf.

Comment: What about my previous questions?

Comment: I can't set up a test case for this since our data is used from a closed system. I don't have access to those data points in a exposed state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unsuccessful in debugging the cause of this issue but our interim solution was to provide our users with a long press action to copy the meta data that is relevant to the user in that view.

Based of this answer: [UIWebView without Copy/Paste when displaying PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768194/uiwebview-without-copy-paste-when-displaying-pdf-files)

```
let longPress =UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(copyOptions))
longPress.allowableMovement = 100
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.3
longPress.delegate = self
longPress.delaysTouchesBegan = true
longPress.delaysTouchesEnded = true
longPress.cancelsTouchesInView = true
self.wrapper.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

func copyOptions () {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Copy", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in

    }))

    if let someValue = self.someObject?.someValue {
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Copy Some Value", style: .default, handler: { action in
            UIPasteboard.general.string = someValue
        }))
    }


    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```